# Domain project deployment failure in Community edition

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have created new domain project in Anypoint studio and it is working from the runtime which is embedded in Anypoint studio. But when I am trying to deploy it in Mule community edition runtime, I am getting the below captioned warn and error. Can anyone please advise whether my application needs any modification?

Error logs:-

```
WARN  2017-05-18 13:12:50,085 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain/current/mule-domain-ee.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

 ERROR 2017-05-18 13:12:50,210 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'domain:mule-domain'.
```

Comment: Thanks Ram, after removing ee from XML prologs, it is working now.

Comment: Sstest, can you accept my answer? That will help others to identify this answer in case they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your deploying the domain application in the community edition, you need to remove the **ee** from the domain schema location. Use the below schema location

`http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/domain/current/mule-domain.xsd`

The solution for this issue is answered here https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/55716/381-community-edition-wont-load-domain-complaining.html